# Apache's reflection equals considering parent and child as equals

Tags: java, equals, apache-commons

Apache's `EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(...)` may consider 2 different types as equals if they have the same attributes. Is this how equals is supposed to behave?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    class A {
        protected int x = 1;
    }

    class B extends A {
    }

    System.out.println(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(new A(), new B()));
    System.out.println(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(new A(), new B(), false, B.class));
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

I made the same experiment with IntelliJ IDEA's auto-generated equals and it does consider both objects different:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class A {
        protected int x = 1;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            A a = (A) o;
            return x == a.x;
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
    }

    System.out.println(new A().equals(new B()));
}
```

Output:

```
false
```

Comment: Well of course, thats the whole point of reflectionEquals()... Use Objects.equals() if you want "normal" behaviour. Reflection equals is something very specific, only compares the inside ;)

Comment: @JanOssowski No, that's not at all "the whole point of reflectionEquals". If it were, two unrelated classes with same fields would compare as equal according to it; they don't.

Comment: What `equals()` means is decided by you, the programmer. It can consider only objects of the same class as equals, it can allow a super and subclass to be equal, or it can even allow unrelated (inheritance-wise) classes to be equal.

Comment: @Kayaman it's indeed up to the developer, but isn't it bad practice or at least very unusual to consider parent and child as equals just because they have the same attributes? I imagine the main reason for `EqualsBuilder` to exist is to be used in the `equals` method. At least I've seen it used this way many times in different teams and companies.

Comment: Depends on the requirements. In the "standard" form the objects need to be the same class, but it's not a hard rule. This is in comment to "is this how equals is *supposed* to behave".

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the source](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html), the relevant part is lines 477-500:

```
477        // Find the leaf class since there may be transients in the leaf
478        // class or in classes between the leaf and root.
479        // If we are not testing transients or a subclass has no ivars,
480        // then a subclass can test equals to a superclass.
481        final Class<?> lhsClass = lhs.getClass();
482        final Class<?> rhsClass = rhs.getClass();
483        Class<?> testClass;
484        if (lhsClass.isInstance(rhs)) {
485            testClass = lhsClass;
486            if (!rhsClass.isInstance(lhs)) {
487                // rhsClass is a subclass of lhsClass
488                testClass = rhsClass;
489            }
490        } else if (rhsClass.isInstance(lhs)) {
491            testClass = rhsClass;
492            if (!lhsClass.isInstance(rhs)) {
493                // lhsClass is a subclass of rhsClass
494                testClass = lhsClass;
495            }
496        } else {
497            // The two classes are not related.
498            isEquals = false;
499            return this;
500        }
```

So they specifically choose to allow this.

The rules for `equals` allow both this approach and the one taken by IDEA (and most other automatic generators, I think).

But as part of an `EqualsBuilder`, the current approach may be preferred because once a check returns `false`, this is the final result, while a `true` can become `false` by comparing classes as well.